# angular strap multiselect drop-down

Tags: angularjs

I am using multi select drop-down from angularstrap module.

When i try out the example given on angularstrap website (http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##getting-started) everything works fine..but trying to incorporate that into my code somehow does not work. My drop-down shows up to be blank.

What am i missing here:
I have created a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f

Comment: That plunker appears to be nothing more than a Hello World stub, did you get the link right, or did you save?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When you turn on the debug console you probably see a sce error.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce)

You have to turn off the sceprovider for your whole app

```
app.config(function($sceProvider) {
    // disable strict context
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
});
```

or make clear that you label is trusted

```
$sce.trustAsHtml(dropdownLabel)
```